# How to filter lookups based on the logged in user?

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, visualforce-component

I have created a portal and the users will be accessing it through the custom tab in the platform.Everything works fine but i have a lookup field which has a lookup to contacts.The contact records which a user doesn't have access to
can also be seen in the lookup.Can anyone please help me to filter these lookups so that the user can see only those contacts which he has access to.

Thanks!!

Comment: Are you sure the user can't access those contacts? Try e.g. searching for them when logged in as the portal user.

Comment: Are you using sharing keyword in your controller

Comment: Are you using the legacy Portal or the Communities product and which licence types are you using as this has an impact on how record visibility is setup.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try this?

Go to --> Security Controls --> Sharing Settings --> Edit (OWD) and 
you will see a check box **Portal User Visiblity** under User Visibility Settings and uncheck the same.